# Proof for Norms in Vector Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Prove that if a norm $\|x\|$ on a real vector space satisfies the parallelogram law, then the polarization identity defines an inner product and that the norm associated with this inner product is the original norm.

I've started by showing that the polarization identity satisfies the three properties of the inner product: that is, symmetry ($x \cdot y = y \cdot x$); bilinearity ( $(ax + by) \cdot z = ax \cdot z + by \cdot z$); and positive definiteness ($x \cdot x \ge 0$ with equality iff $x = 0$).
I have the proofs for symmetry and positive definiteness, but I'm stuck on bilinearity, and I have no idea how to show that the norm associated with the inner product is the original norm.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: See the Proposition 6.8 in http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEYQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.warwick.ac.uk%2Ffac%2Fsci%2Fmaths%2Fpeople%2Fstaff%2Fottobre%2Ffa%2Fv.gelfreichnotesfuncan.pdf&ei=goHRVJzcH8Xs8AX5woLYAQ&usg=AFQjCNHsEHXhJmb0fMCXQNHEmF_HcKU2Zw&bvm=bv.85142067,d.dGc

Comment: I actually just found a complete proof that I'll link here for posterity or whatnot: http://www.pcs.cnu.edu/~jgomez/files/norm.pdf